# How do I remove class from container by searching for the id of the contained div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in my snippet below, I have two container divs that each contain a div with a unique id (`block_1` and `block_2`).

How can I remove the hidden class of one of the containers by looking for the id of `block_1` or `block_2`? jQuery is fine.

Thanks!

```
<div class="col-md-2 hidden">
    <div id="block_1">...</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8 hidden">
    <div id="block_2">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parent()`

```
$("#block_1").parent().removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("#block_1").closest(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");` should do the trick:

- finds the "block_1"
- walks up the dom tree until it finds the "hidden" div
- removes the unnecessary class

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use jQuery `removeClass` method.

```
$("#block_1").parent().removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.parent()` to get parent DIV like and then call `.removeClass` function

```
$("#block_1").parent().removeClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pure JS approach:

```
// Gets parent element of "block_1"
var element = document.getElementById("block_1").parentNode;
// Removes hidden class
element.className = element.className.replace(" hidden","");
```

Answer (score 0):

without jquery:

```
    // get parent node
    var block = document.getElementById('block_1');
    var blockParent = block.parentNode;
    if (blockParent && blockParent.className) {
        // replace specific className with whitespace
        var newClassName = blockParent.className.replace(/\s*\bhidden\b\s*/, ' ');
        // trim
        newClassName = newClassName.replace(/\s*$/, '').replace(/^\s*/, '');
        // update class
        if (blockParent.className !== newClassName) blockParent.className = newClassName;
    }
```